# Is there an event connected to the choice of a datalist <option>?

Tags: javascript, html, html-input, dom-events, html-datalist

I have a (dynamic) list of choices in an `<input>` field:

```html
<input list="choices">
<datalist id="choices">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
</datalist>
```

**Is there an event fired right after the choice of the `<option>` is made?** (which I would like to catch/use in Vue.js if this matters). This would be when the left button of the mouse is clicked in the scenario below:

[image]

Comment: you can trigger .change jquery every when option value is changed

Comment: @ISHIDA: you mean **after the option was chosen**, not **after each keystroke** (and therefore a change of the content of the input field)? That would be great.

Comment: Yes I have provided an example in answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. it will check if the value exist in the input box and alert is triggered when you select an option as you have requested

```
<input list="choices" id="searchbox">
<datalist id="choices">
<option id="one">one</option>
<option>two</option>
</datalist>


$("#searchbox").bind('input', function () {
    if(checkExists( $('#searchbox').val() ) === true){
        alert('item selected')
    }
});

function checkExists(inputValue) {
    console.log(inputValue);

    var x = document.getElementById("choices");
    var i;
    var flag;
    for (i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
        if(inputValue == x.options[i].value){
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, please see https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/pnfa10gk/ - the alert is fired after each change of the input box - the exact thing I want to avoid

Comment: you want to capture mousedown event when selecting options ?

Comment: That could be one option - I was hoping for an event which is triggered when an option from the is chosen (clicked on) -- at that moment I would clear up the search field and use the chosen option

Comment: @WoJ "*clear up the search field and use the chosen option*" - isn't that what chosing the dropdown option does by default?

Comment: @Bergi: I was not clear: when the option is chosen, I want to clear up the search field (so that it is blank) and use the chosen option elsewhere. The problem is that I can monitor the field in Vue and have its **current** content (not obligatory the content of an option) but I do not know when the actual option is chosen (as opposed to a partial find in the serach field). I do that currently by checking the content of the input field (I have values on the options, all of the start with XXX so when the input field starts with XXX I assume it is a chosen value, and not a currently typed string)

Comment: @Bergi: this is why I want to monitor specifically for the **action of choosing an option in the dropdown list**

Comment: @WoJ check this jsfiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/AAfuX/215/
In this it will trigger for every option value selected as you asked.

Comment: You are welcome@WoJ. 
Can I know the reason for down vote, whoever gave it, So that I can improve. 
Thnk you :)

Comment: While exact string match is a clever solution, that still causes problems, namely this will fire the instant anything matches. It's not the same as clicking an item in the list. Additionally, you could never type "foobar" if both "foo" and "foobar" is in the list, because after typing the second 'o' in foo would trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like options in datalist do not tigger any event, so you need to code your own solution.

I was able to do something similar to fire events with options in datalist, using **@input** in the  element

For example in your code you can try a solution starting with this

```
<input list="choices" @input="checkInput" >
<datalist id="choices">
 <option>one</option>
 <option>two</option>
</datalist>
```

In the method used with @input you can check the changes in the input value.

```
  checkInput(e){
    var inputValue = e.target.value;
    //Your code
  },
```

For example you can check if the input value, after click in one option of your datalyst, is a valid option, and after that conditions meets you can launch another method or whatever you want.

Comment: Your solution is to use Vue?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, the solution I described, works only if you use Vue.